# SQL relationships

Tags: sql, relationships

I have four tables:

1. task      - have a batch_id and estimates of how long a task would take to complete
2. batches   - groups of tasks
3. batch_log - entries showing the time worked for each task with a userid for who worked it.
4. operation - type of machine the batch is run on, paint, silkscreen, etc.

How would I get each batch worked for each user, the total elapsed from each batch log for those batch ids and the total estimate from each task id for that batch?

EDIT:

TABLES:

```
task
id     estimated_nonrecurring   estimated_recurring  batch_id

batch
id     operation_id date_entered

batch_log
id     userid    batch_id   time_elapsed

operation
id     name
```

I'm thinking:

```
get each user;
get a list of distinct batch_ids that they worked on;
get a sum of all the time_elapsed from each batch_log for those batch id;
get all the non_recurring and the recurring for each task with each batch_id;

so that the result is like

userid, operation, batch_id, total_elapsed, total_estimate, date_entered
```

The reasoning for doing this is so that it can be possible to rate the users on how productive they are and use these queries in excel. I think I may have to go with two queries:

1. the batch log
2. a query to get the total estimated for each batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT bl.UserId, b.name, t.estimate
FROM batch_log as bl
JOIN batches as b
    ON b.id = bl.batch_id
JOIN task as t
    ON t.id = b.task_id
WHERE bl.UserId = 123
```

Hard to say without any sort of table structure to go by.

Answer (score 1):

select distinct bl.userid , t.batchid from batch_log bl inner join task t on t.taskid = bl.taskid ;

select sum(bl.time_spent) , b.batchid from batch b left join task t on b.batchid = t.batchid inner join batch_log bl on bl.taskid = t.taskid;

select sum(t.estimate) , b.batchid from batch b left join task t on b.batchid = t.batchid ;

Why is it called batch_log but it is about taskes and time spent ?

Comment: Because individual time_elapsed isn't counted on tasks but instead on the whole batch those tasks are in, but the estimates of how long each task should be is on the individual task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the structure of your tables, but something like this should work:

```
select batch.id, 
(select sum(batch.time)
from batch_log 
inner join task on task.id = batch_log.id
where task.batchId = batch.id) as total,
(select sum(task.estimate ) from task where task.batchId = batch.id) as estimate
from batch
inner join task on task.batchId = batch.id
where batch_log.userId = @userId
```